# Facing issue while setup bind9 in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, ubuntu

I am new in docker, I want to build an image with Ubuntu 20.04 and bind9 service installation.

below is my code of docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV TZ=Asia
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils \
    systemctl \
    bind9     

RUN /usr/sbin/named -g -c /etc/bind/named.conf -u bind

RUN systemctl restart bind9
```

I am getting an error like below

```
ERROR:systemctl:Unit bind9.service could not be found.
```

Can anyone help me, after installation of Bind9, why I am getting an error with above command?

Error comes with Docker only, if I run same command in Host environment which is Ubuntu 20.04 then it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally cannot use service management commands (like `service` or `systemctl`, etc) in a container, because there is no service manager running.

Additionally, even if there *were* a service manager running, it wouldn't make any sense to interact with it in a `RUN` command: these commands are part of the image build process, and there are no persistent services running at this point. A `RUN` command runs in an isolated environment that is completely torn down when the `RUN` command completes.

If you want `bind` to start when you run a container using your image, you would need to place the appropriate `bind` command line into the `CMD` option. For example, the [official bind9 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/internetsystemsconsortium/bind9) includes:

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-g", "-c", "/etc/bind/named.conf", "-u", "bind"]
```

(See the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/isc-projects/bind9-docker/blob/v9.16/Dockerfile) for details)

Comment: Hi @larsks, don't know why but that issue was resolved but now it started again, let me update my question, would you please help me thanks

Comment: You should probably open a new question.

Comment: Ok sure, let me do it and update you thanks

Comment: hi @Iarsks, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69662603/dockerfile-bind9-unrecognized-service